# Does neither Symmetric nor Alternating Tensors exist?

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors

I have been reading about tensors. The set of all covariant k-tensors on a vector space V is itself a vector space $ T^{k}(V^{*}) $.

The set of symmetric covariant k-tensors form a subspace of $ T^{k}(V^{*}) $ and denoted by $\Sigma ^ {k} (V^{*}) $.

The set of alternating covariant k-tensors form a subspace of $ T^{k}(V^{*}) $ and denoted by $\Lambda ^ {k} (V^{*}) $.

My question is whether every covariant k-tensor should belong to either of the two subspaces? In other words, are there covariant k-tensors that are neither symmetric nor alternating in $ T^{k}(V^{*}) $ ?

Comment: Consider the sum of a symmetric and alternating tensor.

Comment: It's like asking whether every function must be even or odd, or every complex number must be real or imaginary, or every vector in $\Bbb R^2$ should be parallel to either $\vec{i}$ or $\vec{j}$.

Comment: I see that sum of a symmetric and alternating tensor is neither symmetric nor alternating. Thanks @yeballfrog. So such tensors do exist. My confusion rose from comparing alternating tensors with alternating group which is a subgroup of permutation group. Thanks J.G as well for showing other cases where symmetric and alternating  analogues do not cover the entire space

Comment: @sathishT When $k>2$ there are also tensors which can't be written as the sum of a symmetric tensor and an alternating tensor.

Comment: Thanks @Oscar Cunningham Yes I came across that point when i was reading Introduction to Smooth Manifolds by  Lee. But havent been able to work out an example yet.

Comment: @sathishT Take $k=3$ and work in coordinates. Every symmetric tensor has $s_{112}=s_{121}$, and every alternating tensor has $a_{112}=0$ and $a_{121}=0$. So any tensor with $t_{112}\neq t_{121}$ can't be the sum of a symmetric tensor and an alternating tensor.

Comment: Thanks @OscarCunningham. I was able to verify the example you have provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take in $\Bbb R^2$, for instance, any tensor represented by a matrix which is not symmetric nor skew. Say, the matrix $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$fits the bill and provides $T = e_1\otimes e_1 + e_1\otimes e_2 = e_1\otimes (e_1+e_2)$, where $\{e_1,e_2\}$ is the standard basis.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please show how the given matrix provides the tensor T that you have shown. Sorry if i am being too naive.. but I am not able to work it out.

Comment: Coefficient of $e_i\otimes e_j$ is the $(i,j)$- entry of the matrix. Also see section 1 [here](https://www.asc.ohio-state.edu/terekcouto.1/texts/tensors.pdf).

Comment: Thanks. That was very helpful